# Adding a function in R for use without loading it

Tags: r, function, startup

So I have code for a custom function in R, e.g. simply:

```
f <- function(x) return(x)
```

What I want to do is be able to call this function `f` as if it came with default R. That is, I don't want to have to `source()` the file containing the code to be able to use the function. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Add it to your `.Rprofile`.

Comment: How do I actually do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking to do is documented extensively under [`?Startup`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html). Basically, you need to customize your `Rprofile.site` or `.Rprofile` to include the functions that you want available on startup. A simple guide can be found at [the Quick-R site](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html).

One thing to note: if you are commonly sharing code with others, you do need to remember what you've changed in your startup options and be sure that the relevant functions are also shared.